# PostgreSQL selecting rows which appear maximum number of times

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I have 3 tables. 1 is startups which contains startup id and name, 1 is investor_groups which contains investor id and investor group name, 1 is deals which contains startup_id - The id of the startup that submitted the funding application, and investor_group_id - The id of the investor group that the startup submitted the funding application to.

I have to find the startups which submitted the most applications, and the names of the groups they applied to.

What I'm trying to do is -

```
SELECT S.name AS Startup_name, COUNT(S.name) as num
FROM deals D 
INNER JOIN startups S ON D.startup_id = S.id 
INNER JOIN investor_groups I ON D.investor_group_id = I.id
GROUP BY Startup_name
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 2
```

But this is giving me the result as -

**startup_name, num**

HJ Inc, 3

smoothies, 3

What I want is -

**startup_name, investor_name**

HJ Inc,                abc

HJ Inc ,             def

HJ Inc  ,              ghi

smoothies,             xyz

smoothies,             rst

smoothies,            lmn

When I am adding Investor group names in the SELECT statement, its showing me an error that Investor group names need to be in a GROUP BY statement.

The sample data from the tables -

For table 'startups' 
[startups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJnSW.png)

For table 'investor_groups'
[investor_groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjtuo.png)

For table 'deals'
[deals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5DK8.png)

Comment: Please do NOT supply sample data as images. Just imagine us providing answers as images of SQL queries - wouldn't that be frustrating? You have done the right thing to supply sample data, but just copy/paste it as fixed format text is way better. That way we can create tables and test our solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that. I'm new to this community, so don't have much experience. Thanks for the feedback though, I'll keep that in mind from the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `count() over()`

```
SELECT
      S.name AS Startup_name
    , I.name AS investor_name
    , COUNT(*) over(partition by S.name) AS num
FROM deals D 
INNER JOIN startups S ON D.startup_id = S.id 
INNER JOIN investor_groups I ON D.investor_group_id = I.id
ORDER BY num DESC, Startup_name, investor_name
```